# Using Github and Gitlab

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

### My Problem

I wanted to do commits on Github with my private email `a@gmail.com` and commits to our companys Gitlab with the company email `me@company.com`, without changing the config of Git with every commit. So when I do commits on Github, it's linked to my Github-account and the same for Gitlab.

### What I already made

Therefore I've created two different SSH keys and connected them with Github and Gitlab. I also have a file called `config` in my folder `~/.ssh/` with this in it:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User KonstantinSchuette

Host gitlab.company.com
        HostName gitlab.company.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        User KonstantinSchuette
```

But my commits are not connected to the account that I've linked the keys to.

Comment: `User KonstantinSchuette` -> `User git`

Comment: Test with `ssh -T git@github-work`

Comment: @phd now I made it working, but faced another problem, as described above

Comment: SSH keys don't have emails; perhaps you mean a comment? No, `git` cannot use a comment from an ssh key. Also you must understand that email used in commits are used **during commits** while ssh keys are used **during push**. Two different and unrelated phases. So git can only use config (or env var) to get email, not an ssh key.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I thought that SSH keys are used to make commits with different accounts on Github and Gitlab, so that it overrides the config. But thats not the case. I need to adapt the config

Comment: For me needed change `gitlab.company.com` on `gitlab.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What I misunderstood

I thought that SSH keys are used to make commits with different accounts on Github and Gitlab, so that it overrides the config. But thats not the case. They are only used to get access from different accounts to different platforms, without typing in the credentials of an account.

### Solution

I needed to create different folders for Github and Gitlab to load a different config for Git, when I'm working on Github and Gitlab projects at the same time. So only repositorys from Github are in the Github-folder and only Gitlab repositorys are in the Gitlab-folder.

I edited my `~/.gitconfig` to that:

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Desktop/Github/"]
  path=.gitconfig-Github
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Desktop/Gitlab/"]
  path=.gitconfig-Gitlab
```

And in the same directory as the `.gitconfig` i created the `.gitconfig-Github`:

```
[user]
name=Dewey
email=a@gmail.com
```

and also a `.gitconfig-Gitlab`:

```
[user]
name=Dewey
email=me@company.com
```

I'm using VSCode so it was essential that the `includeIf` starts with `gitdir/i:` to turn off case-sensitive. If you don't do this step your config will not be loaded when you use VSCode.

I've found the solution to that on the issue board for VSCode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62921

Now everything works as I wanted it to.